# How do I upgrade Gradle?

Tags: apt, upgrade, versions, ubuntu-make, gradle

This shows that `Gradle` is up to date:

```
thufir@doge:~$ sudo apt install gradle
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
gradle is already the newest version (2.10-1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 629 not upgraded.
```

How do I upgrade to `Gradle` 4.x?  Preferably, with [umake](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make) rather than SDKMAN! which seems to be what they [suggest](https://gradle.org/install/).

(I don't want to update all the packages due to a slow connection.)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You could use [the ppa](https://launchpad.net/~cwchien/+archive/ubuntu/gradle) for the almost-always latest version

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade gradle
```

or [SDKMAN](https://sdkman.io/install) for the latest version

```
curl -s "https://get.sdkman.io" | bash
source "$HOME/.sdkman/bin/sdkman-init.sh"
sdk install gradle
```

Advantages of the ppa

- auto-updates with the system
- no piping of downloaded scripts to the shell

Advantages of sdkman: latest version [supplied by gradle themselves](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/installation.html).

Comment: I got error while running `upgrade gradle` as `The following packages have unmet dependencies.
 powershell : Depends: liblttng-ust0 but it is not installed` . I have to run this `sudo apt-get -f install` then `sudo apt-get -f install gradle`. This way, it deletes the previous one and installs the latest from scratch.

Comment: @AnumSheraz: powershell is in another repository altogether. It should not have anything to do with gradle. But it seems like `sudo apt-get -f install` fixed its problem.

Comment: you're lifesaver. My gradle version was 2 and throws that exception: gradle failed to apply plugin id 'com.google.protobuf' After update gradle the problem is gone. Thanks.

Comment: This PPA does not serve up-to-date Gradle. Now my Gradle version is 5.2 (installed via `apt`) while there's 5.3.1 available for download from the official website.

Comment: @naXa: if you really need the very latest, see the update. You will miss out on automatic updates.

Comment: @naXa:  the ppa has been updated to 5.3.1

Comment: I had to remove the installed version with
`sudo apt remove gradle`
and then install the new version with the ppa to update to the newest version.

Comment: In Ubuntu 23.04 there's also a Gradle snap, i.e., `sudo snap install gradle` will install Gradle 7.2. You may need to `apt-get remove gradle` if `/usr/bin/` comes earlier than `/snap/bin` in your `$PATH` or specify the full path until you can use a Gradle wrapper (see my answer below).

Comment: Why does it install so old version by default?

Comment: There is an error when I try to run the first command: `sudo: add-apt-repository: command not found`

Comment: @GeorgeShalvashvili: please check https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45879/how-to-add-repository-from-shell-in-debian: `sudo apt-get install software-properties-common`

Answer (score 23):

You can also tell Gradle to update itself using a Gradle wrapper.

First you create the wrapper, then tell it to use the Gradle version of your choice:

```
gradle wrapper
./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version 4.9
```

Now this project will use Gradle 4.9, independent of what's installed.
However, you need to remember to run Gradle through the wrapper, i.e., run `./gradlew` instead of plain `gradle`.

The wrapper allows you to have different projects using different Gradle versions easily.

When you commit the created wrapper to source control, everybody who checks out the project will use the same Gradle version. This can help a lot with incompatible build scripts, when something has changed between Gradle versions.

Comment: I cannot generate the wrapper because the system gradle is too old

Comment: @CsabaToth Install the Gradle snap (`sudo snap install gradle`) and uninstall the system Gradle so that it doesn't try to use that.

Answer (score 2):

download from  https://gradle.org/releases/

pick the binary-only link as per

> v4.10.3
>
> Dec 05, 2018
>
> Download: binary-only or complete

after you expand the download just update your PATH env var to pickup this new binary

```
vi ~/.bashrc  # or where ever your shell's env vars are defined
```

and add following line to bottom of ~/.bashrc

```
#   replace ~/src/gradle-4.10.3/bin with your location
export PATH=~/src/gradle-4.10.3/bin:$PATH
```

confirm this works by issuing

```
source ~/.bashrc
gradle --version
```