# How to upgrade Gradle to 6.7.1

Tags: apt, gradle

I need to use gradle 6.7 and followed [this advice](https://askubuntu.com/questions/932083/how-do-i-upgrade-gradle) trying to upgrade:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cwchien/gradle
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt upgrade gradle
```

which logs out among others:

```
Get:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cwchien/gradle/ubuntu focal/main amd64 gradle all 6.7.1-0ubuntu1 [3.432 B]
Fetched 3.432 B in 0s (13,2 kB/s)  
Selecting previously unselected package gradle.
(Reading database ... 285000 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../gradle_6.7.1-0ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking gradle (6.7.1-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up gradle (6.7.1-0ubuntu1) ...
```

Oh great, I'm thinking, it's installed gradle 6.7.1! But unfortunately nothing has changed:

`gradle --version`

```
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 6.6.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2020-08-25 16:29:12 UTC
Revision:     f2d1fb54a951d8b11d25748e4711bec8d128d7e3

Kotlin:       1.3.72
Groovy:       2.5.12
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.8 compiled on May 10 2020
JVM:          1.8.0_275 (Private Build 25.275-b01)
OS:           Linux 5.4.0-60-generic amd64
```

`which gradle` points to `/usr/bin/gradle` which is a symlink

`/usr/bin/gradle -> /etc/alternatives/gradle`

Answer (score -1):

**Download latest version of gradle in /tmp dir (https://gradle.org/releases/)**

cd /tmp

wget https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

**Unzip downloaded file**

sudo unzip -d /opt/gradle /tmp/gradle-7.3.3-bin.zip

sudo ln -s /opt/gradle/gradle-7.3.3 /opt/gradle/latest

**Setting up the Environment Variables**

sudo nano /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh

#Add below two lines:

export GRADLE_HOME=/opt/gradle/latest

export PATH=${GRADLE_HOME}/bin:${PATH}

**Make above created script executable:**
sudo chmod +x /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh

**Load environment variables:**
source /etc/profile.d/gradle.sh

**Verify gradle installation**

gradle -v

**Output**: Welcome to Gradle 7.3.3!

**Follow below link for detailed instructions:**

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-gradle-on-ubuntu-20-04/